# Matrix setScale Function is not working as expected

Tags: android, image-scaling

I have this code for resizing an image : 
Java :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView iv, iv2;
    private float scaley = 1f;
    private float scaley2 = 1f;
    private GestureDetectorCompat detector;
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    Matrix m2 = new Matrix();
    private RelativeLayout root;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        iv2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {


                scaley -= distanceY / root.getHeight();
                m.setScale(1, scaley, 0, 0);
                iv.setImageMatrix(m);


                scaley2 += distanceY / root.getHeight();
                m2.setScale(1, scaley2);
                int imageHeight = iv2.getDrawable().getMinimumHeight();
                m2.postTranslate(0, iv2.getHeight() - (imageHeight * scaley2));
                iv2.setImageMatrix(m2);

              return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/root">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"

            android:src="@drawable/as" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/as"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want my `second` image to have a pivot on its bottom, so I use  this part :

```
scaley2 += distanceY / root.getHeight();
                m2.setScale(1, scaley2);
                int imageHeight = iv2.getDrawable().getMinimumHeight();
                m2.postTranslate(0, iv2.getHeight() - (imageHeight * scaley2));
                iv2.setImageMatrix(m2);
```

It works, image looks anchored at the  bottom but, it's not growing, when I try to grow the image, it stays at its default size. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer and created a sample project on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

I found the cleanest way to do this is to have the two `ImageView`s overlap, then calculate the rectangles that the images should occupy based on the touch event and just set the matrix to map the image bounds to the rectangle bounds, ex:

```
        // after setting image resource, get the bounds of the bitmap
        Drawable drawable = mImageView1.getDrawable();
        image1Bounds.set(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        drawable = mImageView2.getDrawable();
        image2Bounds.set(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

        // use the Y coord of touch event as bottom of imageView1 and top of imageView2
        imageView1Bounds.set(0, 0, mImageView1.getMeasuredWidth(), event.getY());
        imageView2Bounds.set(0, event.getY(), mImageView2.getMeasuredWidth(), mImageView2.getMeasuredHeight());

        // set the matrices to transform the images to their respective bounds
        mMatrix1.setRectToRect(image1Bounds, imageView1Bounds, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        mMatrix2.setRectToRect(image2Bounds, imageView2Bounds, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);

        mImageView1.setImageMatrix(mMatrix1);
        mImageView2.setImageMatrix(mMatrix2);
```

You can see the entire working project at: https://github.com/klarson2/Matrix

---

If you want to anchor the bottom of the image to the bottom of the `ImageView`, your best bet is to add a translation that will do that.

```
            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            scaley += distanceY / root.getHeight();
            m.setScale(1, scaley);  // no pivot here
            int imageHeight = iv.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
            m.postTranslate(0, iv.getHeight() - (imageHeight * scaley));
            iv.setImageMatrix(m);
            return true;
```

Also I would recommend allocating a new `Matrix` once during initialization and then reusing that Matrix in `onScroll()` to improve performance.

Comment: That works, thanks, but when I try to grow image, it's not growing more than it's actual height. How can I fix that?

Comment: I also changed `iv.getDrawable().getHeight();` to `iv.getHeight();` because it didn't work.

Comment: That `scaley` calculation is probably not right.  I've only done this with pinch-zoom and `ScaleGestureDetector` (i.e. two fingers).  My guess is that you have to override `onDown` and grab the initial y position of the scroll, then use that somewhere in your `onScroll` to calculate the scale.

Comment: Yeah, I'd have to set up a test project to make sure I got it right.  Is your code in GitHub or somewhere I can see it?

Comment: That's all the code I have. You need an extra relative layout, and imageview and a random image.

Comment: I added all of the java and XML code I have to the question. I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you update your question?  I'm not sure I totally understand how you want the scroll motion on the entire screen to affect the image zooms.  For example, pinch-zooms have the principle of least surprise where the change in the distance between your fingers indicates the change in the scale. And how big can the images get, how small can they get, etc.  Just a few more details so I know I've got it straight.

Comment: In my configuration, when user swipes up,above image becomes smaller and its pivoted to the top.below image gets bigger and pivoted to the bottom. When user swipes down, above image gets bigger and pivoted to the top and below image gets smaller and pivoted to the bottom.that's all how it works. Thank you. This is correct configuration

Comment: Could you understand what I need or you need more clarifications?

Comment: Just didn't get a chance to look at it.  I edited my answer to use `getIntrinsicHeight` for the height of the image.  Try that first. The idea is that you to do the scale operation first, then see how high the scaled image is and translate it so that the bottom is aligned with the view. Now did you want the edges of the two images to stay joined to each other when one scales smaller and the other scales larger?

Comment: I wanted the edges of two images to stay in touch with each other.

Comment: I edited the answer and added a link to my sample project on GitHub.